# How to upload images from local path to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, react-native-fetch-blob, aws-amplify

I am developing a React Native application and trying to upload an image stored on the device to S3. I know the path to the image but when I try to upload the image, S3 returns an unsupported file error or uploads the file with its name but the file only contains the file path string.

I am using [aws-amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) to establish these connections.

Here is the code block that I use:

```
 const file = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir}/${localFilePath}`;
 Storage.put("exampleFolder/" + userId + ".jpeg", file)
                .then(result => console.log(result))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice example in the [aws-mobile-react-native-starter](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-native-starter/blob/master/client/src/Screens/AddPet.js#L128) repo.
You just need to read the file, and then you can upload it.

```
return files.readFile(imagePath)
  .then(buffer => Storage.put(key, buffer, { level: 'private', contentType: result.type }))
  .then(fileInfo => ({ key: fileInfo.key }))
  .then(x => console.log('SAVED', x) || x);
```

To read the file they've used `react-native-fetch-blob`:

```
readFile(filePath) {
    return RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(filePath, 'base64').then(data => new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the text as the content of the file, not file as in binary

Like below will store Hello in S3 file

```
Storage.put('test.txt', 'Hello')
    .then (result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Try mentioning contentType, for your case image/png, as in below example for text file

```
Storage.put('test.txt', 'Private Content', {
    level: 'private',
    contentType: 'text/plain'
})
```

Take inspiration from blow URLs:
https://viblo.asia/p/serverless-mobile-application-development-made-with-react-native-and-aws-mobilehub-Az45bnmQ5xY#11-add-source-code-15

https://gist.github.com/zeroFruit/d46d4cae57e5e8cf59e1b541c0bf322e

Code from first URL mentioned above

```
import Amplify, { API, Storage } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

import { awsmobile } from './aws-exports'; // point path of aws-exports.js
import files from './files'; // point path of files.js

Amplify.configure(awsmobile);  


saveImage = () => {
  const options = {
    title: 'Select Avatar',
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: 'images'
    }
  };

  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
    console.log('Response = ', response);

    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    }
    else if (response.error) {
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    }
    else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    }
    else {
      RNFetchBlob
      .config({
        fileCache: true,
        appendExt: 'png',
      })
      .fetch('GET', response.uri, {
      })
      .then((res) => {
        // upload to storage
        files.readFile(res.data)
          .then(buffer => Storage.put('image.png', buffer, { level: 'public', contentType: 'image/png' }))
          .then(x => console.log('SAVED', x) || x);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution also seems to work however @RadekCzemerys answer is more direct.

Comment: Yes, agree. Thanks for the comment. (Not a react guy, but a googler :p)